# Poisson's Equation, getting more than one answer to something that should be unique

Tags: vector-analysis

Consider the equation $\nabla^2f = 0$ on a smooth volume $V$ such that on the boundary $f(x) = u(x)$ for some specified function $u$ . This has a unique solution: Suppose that $f_1,f_2$ are solutions. Then let $F = f_1-f_2$ and note $\nabla^2 F = 0$ and $F = 0$ on the boundary . Also by Divergence theorem $$ 0 = \int_{\partial V}F\nabla F \cdot dS =\int_V \nabla\cdot(F\nabla F) \  dV = \int_VF\nabla^2F + |{\nabla F}|^2 \ dV = \int_V |{\nabla F}|^2 \ dV$$ So as $|{\nabla F}|^2 \geq 0$ we get that $\nabla F = 0$ everywhere so $F = 0$ so $f_1 = f_2$.

However if we let $V$ be the sphere of radius $1$ centred at the origin then the equation with the boundary condition $f = 0$ on surface with f spherically symmetric, then $\nabla^2f = 0$ has the solution $f = A/r-A$ for all real $A$. However this implies the solution is not unique. Any hints on what I am missing are much appreciated.

Comment: You can write all your solutions as a scalar multiple of the fundamental solution $\frac{1}{r}-1$. So you really have only 1 independent solution. The coefficient $A$ could be fixed with an additional boundary condition.

Comment: However if I consider a slightly different problem where I want to solve $\nabla^2f = 1$, then the general solution is $A/r -(A+1/6) + r^2/6$ where  and now I have a completely different solution for each value of $A$!

Comment: In this case you are working with nonhomogeneous equations and you get the sum of a solution of the homogeneous one (the one you first mentioned) and the particular one as a general solution.

Comment: So what this means is that your eventual solution set is of the form $\{A\varphi+\chi_0\}$ where $\varphi$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation and $\chi_0$ is particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation. This also implies that you indeed obtain a different example for every different choice of $A$.

Comment: The solution you have are not defined at $r=0$ and $\nabla^2 f$ is not zero there (these are solutions to $\nabla^2 f = -4\pi A \delta(r)$). In your derivation the second integral (for $f = A/r - A$) is something like $\int_0^1 4\pi A^2 \frac{{\rm d}r}{r^2}$ which does not exist. The only differentiable solutions to $\nabla^2 f = 0$ with $f = 0$ on the boundary is $f\equiv 0$.